# Difference between withContext and suspendCancellableCoroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to coroutines

This is a popular example:

```
suspend fun findBigPrime(): BigInteger =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random()))
    }
```

However, it could be written as well as:

```
suspend fun findBigPrime(): BigInteger =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine {
        it.resume(BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random()))
    }
```

What's the real difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the real difference?

There's hardly any relationship, in fact.

```
suspendCancellableCoroutine {
    it.resume(BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random()))
}
```

This does nothing but add useless overhead above the simple direct call

```
BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random())
```

If you resume the continuation while still inside the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block, the coroutine doesn't suspend at all.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random()))
}
```

This suspends the coroutine and launches an internal coroutine on another thread. When the internal coroutine completes, it resumes the current one with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `suspendCancellableCoroutine` here is a "BIG NO".

`withContext` changes the context on which the block (coroutine) will run, here the Dispatcher which dispatches the coroutine to a specified thread is overridden. While the `suspendCoroutine`/`suspendCancellableCoroutine` are used for wrapping asynchronous callbacks which does not block the thread instead they run on thread of their own.

Usually work on the `suspendCoroutine`/`suspendCancellableCoroutine` is non-blocking and gets completed quite quickly and the continuation is resumed after the work has completed in a non-blocking way maybe in other thread or so.

If you put blocking code in there the concept of coroutine is lost, it will just going to block the thread it is running on.

**Use of `suspendCoroutine`/`suspendCancellableCoroutine`:**

```kotlin
// This function immediately creates and starts thread and returns
fun findBigPrimeInNewThread(after: (BigInteger) -> Unit) {
    Thread {
        BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random()).also(after)
    }
}

// This just wraps the async function so that when the result is ready resume the coroutine
suspend fun findBigPrime(): BigInteger =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        findBigPrimeInNewThread {
            cont.resume(it)
        }
    }
```